# Creating Android Studio Layout with complete screen as background

Tags: java, android, image, layout, background

I have already created complete screens for my App in the development process using **spark**. These images are the complete screens including `buttons` etc. I have set them as `android: background` and put buttons with `android:background="@null"` in the places where the buttons are in the images.
 My Intention was to avoid designing all the screens in android studio and instead just setting the whole screen as a background and laying invisible buttons in the correct spots for functionality. Now I have run into the Problem that my Buttons are in different places depending on the device. I am using relative layouts for this. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> my Buttons are in different places depending on the device. I am using relative layouts for this.

I would recommend that you use constraintlayout if you want things to scale. Then use vertical & horizontal bias to position your buttons where they need to be.

If you are struggling with your parent layout changing between devices, use the constraintDimensionRatio, like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/layoutMap"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H, 2 : 1"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

You may need to create separate layouts for portrait and landscape if need be.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I don't really want things to just scale. I need the buttons and textViews to scale and move exactly the way they move in my background picture. So that the buttons displayed in my background image align with the buttons with actual functionality. Would that work with a constraintLayout?

Comment: If you want your invisible buttons to move along with background image, then yes I believe this is the best option for you. Use "bias" to position your buttons, and that will scale the position no matter how the dimensions of your background image change. There is some nuance to it, as you may be forced to crop one side of your background image out to scale to fit either the height or width.